# Оставить несколько символов после знака

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Нужна помощь. Пытаюсь на bash сделать так, что бы оставался один символ после `,`. Как то так:

```
Введите число:
14352,3532345
Ваше число:
14352,3

Введите число:
356,453
Ваше число:
356,4
```

Буду благодарен!

Comment: А если нет запятой?

Comment: А ввод только с запятой, я это в другую программу вставлю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем-то, sed, например:

```sh
$ echo '123,456' | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{1,\},[0-9]\).*/\1/g'
123,4
```